# git-cvsserver pserver username propagation

Tags: git, git-cvs

For some specific workflow issues at my company, I need to allow some users work 
with CVS, while main repository is under git.

I've chosen git-cvsserver as implementation for this task.

I set up git repository, enabled it for gitcvs and setup a pserver simulation on 
xinetd. Everything works fine, I can work with this repository from cvs client, 
authenticating against passwd file I created through pserver emulation.

My problem is that commits that I make through CVS are shown under user who runs 
xinetd, not under user I authenticate against passwd.

i.e. I commit to CVS as user 'foo', I successfully authenticate through pserver, 
but when I look at git history of commits for this repo, i see that commit has 
been made by user 'root'.

I looked through source of git-cvsserver (http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=git-cvsserver.perl) and it seems that CVS login is used 
only for authentication, not for actual committing.
Records in SQLite database contain 'root' username too, not 'foo'

Do you have any ideas how I can propagate CVS login to git username?

xref at git mailing list: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/169182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no specific experience with it, but `git-cvsserver` almost certainly invokes `git-commit` to do the actual work.  You can get `git-commit` to use anything you want for the author and committer by setting environment variables like `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` (also `..._NAME` and `..._DATE` and `..._IDENT`).  If you have the authentication information available you could simply set it in `$ENV` before the actual commit.  If `git-cvsserver` doesn't clean its environment you could actually set those from the authentication information in a wrapper before invoking it (just *in case* of any commit).

Comment: Great advice, thank you! I just added setting ENV variables for GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL, GIT_COMMITER_NAME and GIT_COMMITER_EMAIL in git-cvsserver, under pserver auth part. Now usernames from cvs clients are propagated into git

Answer (score 0):

Before propagating the login, as shown in [Ben Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479989/ben-jackson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331065/6309), with `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`/`EMAIL` environment variables, make sure the authentication step did run properly.

Before Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git cvsserver`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1030daecda44a36c9c0b02d4f58473b637c49ff5/Documentation/git-cvsserver.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsserver))</sup> had a long-standing bug in its authentication code, which has finally been corrected (it is unclear and is a separate question if anybody is seriously using it, though).

See [commit 4b81f69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b81f690f63111586dc28e7ec103179b98c286bc), [commit bffcb4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bffcb4d9d6394a68a7f6c03598087705c6d34510), [commit a7775c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7775c7eb8074fcf37f22bdcdc0971448c1aa4d1) (15 Sep 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1030dae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1030daecda44a36c9c0b02d4f58473b637c49ff5), 03 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-cvsserver`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7775c7eb8074fcf37f22bdcdc0971448c1aa4d1): use crypt correctly to compare password hashes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>

> [c057bad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c057bad3701682a208b72473b746de6bb5d89792) ("`git-cvsserver`: use a password file cvsserver pserver", 2010-05-15, Git v1.7.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5080d8e10915daa57b5b42c887483d202b45c55)) adds a way for [`git cvsserver`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a7775c7eb8074fcf37f22bdcdc0971448c1aa4d1/Documentation/git-cvsserver.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsserver))</sup> to provide authenticated pserver accounts without having clear text passwords, but uses the username instead of the password to the call for `crypt(3)`.
>
> Correct that, and make sure the documentation correctly indicates how to obtain hashed passwords that could be used to populate this configuration, as well as correcting the hash that was used for the tests.
>
> This change will require that any user of this feature updates the hashes in their configuration, but has the advantage of using a more similar format than cvs uses, probably also easing any migration.

`git cvsserver` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a7775c7eb8074fcf37f22bdcdc0971448c1aa4d1/Documentation/git-cvsserver.txt#L121):

> files, but only with the `-d` option (or `-B` if your system supports it).

`git cvsserver` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a7775c7eb8074fcf37f22bdcdc0971448c1aa4d1/Documentation/git-cvsserver.txt#L123-L125):

> Preferably use the system specific utility that manages password hash
> creation in your platform (e.g. `mkpasswd` in Linux, `encrypt` in OpenBSD or
> `pwhash` in NetBSD) and paste it in the right location.

---

2023: Warning, `crypt(3)` is no longer used, and Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) adapts to it.

See [commit 0856f13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0856f13abaea5f8d3915dd60e7221e108ce14fdf), [commit 5d70afa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d70afa5d81ee7bbd25e875512f9fc3824b096b6), [commit 7d05974](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d05974d725a68b2498b2b0041e5e1e01c0187ac) (10 Nov 2023) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0946acf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0946acfb50b77adbe4f9edf5c1d270a00b376e37), 09 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`t/lib-httpd`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d70afa5d81ee7bbd25e875512f9fc3824b096b6): stop using legacy `crypt(3)` for authentication
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When setting up httpd for our tests, we also install a passwd and proxy-passwd file that contain the test user's credentials.
> These credentials currently use `crypt(3)` as the password encryption schema.
>
> This schema can be considered deprecated nowadays as it is not safe anymore.
> Quoting [Apache httpd's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html):
>
> > Unix only.
> > Uses the traditional Unix crypt(3) function with a
> > randomly-generated 32-bit salt (only 12 bits used) and the first 8
> > characters of the password. Insecure.
>
> This is starting to cause issues in modern Linux distributions.
>
> **glibc has deprecated its libcrypt library that used to provide `crypt(3)` in favor of the `libxcrypt` library**.
> This newer replacement provides a compile time switch to disable insecure password encryption schemata, which causes `crypt(3)` to always return `EINVAL`.
> The end result is that httpd tests that exercise authentication will fail on distros that use `libxcrypt` without these insecure encryption schematas.
>
> Regenerate the passwd files to instead use the default password encryption schema, which is md5.
> While it feels kind of funny that an MD5-based encryption schema should be more secure than anything else, it is the current default and supported by all platforms.
> Furthermore, it really doesn't matter all that much given that these files are only used for testing purposes anyway.